# Difference between "copy all as curl" vs " copy as curl" In Google Chrome Developer console Network Tab

Tags: curl, google-developers-console

I see two options to copy the request from the Google Chrome Developer Tools - > Networks.

```
1. copy as curl"
2. copy all as curl
```

What is the difference between these two?

Comment: "copy all" appears to be literally all of the requests in the network tab, whereas the former is only the one you selected. Just do "copy all", paste it somewhere and look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy all curl will copy all the requests present in network tab

copy as curl will only copy the one you clicked on